# Does "https" package of NodeJS make "http" redundant?

Tags: node.js, http

When I learned NodeJS a few years ago, 'http' module had been introduced.
But I suppose, it's not the best native module from the viewpoint of security and other functionality in 2021.
The first that one that attracts the most attention is **https**.

I know that the HTTPS protocol is an essential of web development for the 2020's.
But does the `https` package fully substitute the `http` module, and will it work if no `https` domain is available in a certain project?

Comment: Think about how you might make a request to an `http` server that exists in the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But does `https` package fully substitutes the `http` and will it work if no https domain available in specific project?

`https` does not substitute `http`, because `https` specifically expects communication under the HTTPS protocol.

```js
const req = require('https').request('http://www.example.com');
```

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol "http:" not supported. Expected "https:"
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:152:11)
    at Object.request (https.js:314:10)
    at repl:1:17
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:120:20)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:433:29)
    at bound (domain.js:426:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:439:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:760:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL'
}
```

Whether there is ever interest in making the `https` module sufficiently flexible to also work with HTTP (with the purpose of making the `http` module redundant), regardless of the security implications, is a matter of opinion and eventual design decisions of Node.js, but seems too unlikely. Heavy changes to the Node.js standard library would affect a major portion of the JavaScript ecosystem, and those projects would not stop depending on `http` so soon, even with such a change.

In practice, one is better off using one of the many [user-friendly HTTP client libraries out there](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143), most of which handle both protocols automatically.

Comment: But, internally these user-friend http client libraries use either the https or the http module depending upon the URL you give them.  So, the http module is still necessary.

Comment: @jfriend00 Indeed, that would be one of the many reasons to keep the module. :) Even if `https` suddenly starts working for URLs with the `http` scheme, we still have existing code depending on `http`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So, if to use the native modules only and customer will say "I want to migrate from http to https", it means the rewriting of the application?

Comment: @TakesiTokugawaYD Using native modules would require you to inspect the URL scheme and pick the right module depending on it. Using a client library (such as `superagent`, `axios`, `node-fetch`, etc.) makes it substantially easier and less error prone to work with both cases.